What happens if a pulsed laser beam is directly incident on the objective lens of a microscope?
I am currently building a microscope in my lab.
In my setup, the pulsed laser beam is directly incident on the objective lens, rather than the typical configuration where collimated light is incident from the back of the lens.
Is this approach advisable? I am concerned about potential damage to the objective lens, as it contains multiple internal components. Could the laser focus on certain elements inside the objective and cause harm? The objective I am using is designed for DIC (Differential Interference Contrast) imaging, as I plan to incorporate additional components for DIC imaging in the future.
The current configuration of the system is shown in the attached picture.

I have used a laser with a microscope objective before with no problems. I also had the laser go througha beam expander initially so that it would fully cover the objective, though.

"pulsed laser" is too broad of a term. Pulse energy and duration are needed. However, from your picture it seems to me that you are simply shining a collimated laser beam onto the object side of an objective. I would not worry too much, unless if you are using quite the powerful laser.
